# I'm unable to add more OpenID providers to my account

Tags: support, profile-page, openid

I want to add a few backup OpenID providers to my account. Should be easy enough to:

- open my profile page
- click "my logins"
- click "add more logins…"
- choose, say, Google and authenticate with them
- be redirected to the StackOverflow account page that now merrily shows me my real Name and a reputation count of 1.

It's the last point I'm a *bit* confused about.

If I re-authenticate via myOpenID I get to my regular account, with "myOpenID" being the only authentication provider in the list.

I see the same behavior when I choose Facebook, which is the other provider I'm prepared to use.

It happens with Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer alike. It happens on stackoverflow.com and stackexchange.com.

What gives?

Comment: generally the mapping is based on email address. If you want things to equate to "you", use the same email address when possible.

Comment: @Jeff I see. Gmail is what I use as my email address, but I've added a tag to it (Google allows appending a suffix like this: `name+suffix@gmail.com` is equivalent to `name@gmail.com`. Maybe a future version of SE can take that into account? For now, I try changing my address.